# How to fire ActiveX ComboBox Change event?

Tags: vba, excel, combobox

New to forums, so please excuse me for any improper formatting...

I am trying to write a simple piece of code that populates static values into a range based on which item is selected in my ComboBox. So far, I have tried using ComboBox_Change, ComboBox_Click, ComboBox_AfterUpdate, and ComboBox_LostFocus, yet none of these options update my worksheet upon selecting one of the ComboBox items.

The below code is what I have so far...

```
Private Sub Workbook_open()
  Sheet8.ComboBox1.Clear
    With Sheet8.ComboBox1
      .AddItem "OK"
      .AddItem "TX"
  End With
End Sub 

Private Sub ComboBox_Change()
  Select Case Sheet8.ComboBox1.Value
    Case "TX"
        Sheet8.Range("H4:H364").Value = 0.046
        Sheet8.Range("I4:I364").Value = 0.075
    Case "OK"
        Sheet8.Range("H4:H52").Value = 0.04
        Sheet8.Range("H53:H364").Value = 0.07
        Sheet8.Range("I4:I364").Value = 0.07
  End Select
End Sub
```

Functionally, the code works after manually clicking "Run" in the Macro window. However, my goal is to have the selected ranges update automatically after selecting one of the ComboBox items.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If it is an ActiveX Combobox then the code needs to be in the code area of the relevant sheet i.e in `Sheet8` code area. I suspect it is in `ThisWorkbook`

Comment: And check your combobox name if it is really `ComboBox` and not `ComboBox1` or something. The `Sub` name must be the combobox name suffixed with `_Change()`.

Comment: @Peh: Lol I missed that... I think it is `ComboBox1` because of `Select Case Sheet8.ComboBox1.Value`

Comment: @SiddharthRout I think we both are right (there are 2 issues) because the code is below the procedure `Workbook_open()` which lets me assume that is is in the workbook area.

Comment: Thank you both! The code was in ' ThisWorkbook ' rather than in 'Sheet8'. Moving it to 'Sheet8' and changing the sub name to 'ComboBox1' did the trick.

Comment: @SiddharthRout After closing and then re-opening the workbook, I noticed that the items within `ComboBox1` do not automatically populate. They require Developer to be opened and manually clicking run to populate. After doing, so the operation works smoothly. Any suggestions?

Comment: Search google on how to activate macros